# Is there a way to get different Google calendars syncing with different Apple devices?

Tags: ios, calendar, google-calendar, google-sync

I'm trying to sync several Google calendars with my iPhone, iPad and Mac, but I don't want *all* of my Google calendars to show up on the phone, just a certain few. You used to be able to go to the Google sync settings and choose which calendars to sync with which device, but when I tried to make some changes today (at google. com/sync/index.html), it changed for all of my devices (iPhone, iPad, Mac mini). Searching Google Support confirmed this is intended (https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/99358):

> If you’d like to sync any additional calendars, or remove any of My calendars from syncing, visit https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect and select the calendars you’d like displayed. Refresh iCal, or close and restart in order to see your new selection.
>
> These settings will apply to any device you sync using CalDAV, such as your iPhone or other iOS device.

Is there still a way to get different Google calendars syncing with different Apple devices?

**Edit:** To clarify, say I have Google calendars A, B, and C. I want my Mac to sync with all three (A, B, C), but I want my iPad to sync with A & B, and my iPhone to sync with just A. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I hope this isn't too much of a Google-centric question, rather than an Apple-centric question.

Comment: Bit confusing...If you do not have certain Google calender on certain devices then there is no syncing.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you decide at  https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect which calendars are to be synced with CalDav devices. No more, no less.

On the devices themself you can choose which calendars you want them to displayed. (It know this is quite trivial, but I do not quite see why this does not suffice).

Alternatively I would suggest creating mutiple Google accounts each one with its own CalDav syncing settings.
For each one you can decide which calendars are to be shared via CalDav. Each of your devices would be connected with one of these Google Account.
Then you share calendars among the Google accounts.

E.g.: Lets say A has all the calendars. You have an iPad and an iPhone. For each one create a google account (B and C). Now A shares the iPad related calendars with B and the iPhone related calendars with C. The iPad syncs with B, the iPhone with C.

It is not ideal but once set up it should run without any overhead.